# Ubuntu is not working after a RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ram, 22.04

Recently I upgraded my notebook's RAM memory from 6 BG (4GB + 2 GB) to 16 GB (8 GB + 8GB). My notebook has Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 22.04 installed on dual boot. When I started Windows it worked fine, and I can even see that the RAM is working correctly:

[image: CPU-Z screen with the RAM memory information]

However, when I try to initialize Ubuntu I get a black screen after the loading. I tried to boot Ubuntu on recovery mode to see if I could fix something, and I found out that Ubuntu is also recognizing the new memory, but for some reason is still not booting:

[image]

As Windows is running correctly I think this is a problem with Ubuntu and not with the RAM sticks. How should I try to solve this?

Comment: Your output clearly says "read-only filesystem". Look up why that happens and what you should do about it.

Comment: I'd also do a memory test... I've had a situation before where ram was added & the RO file-system was the fault of bad RAM... as windows/linux allocate from opposite ends of the RAM so issues can occur in one at different times than the other..  but the RO file-system is a different issue (*bad RAM could cause it maybe though user caused issue too*)